# How do I spawn a zombie wearing a helmet?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to spawn a zombie wearing a helmet but every time I try it, it ends up holding the helmet instead of wearing it. What command do I use to make the zombie wear the helmet instead of hold it, if I'm playing version 1.10?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to specify the equipment as an array.

`/summon Zombie ~0 ~1 ~0 {ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:diamond_helmet}]}`

[image: Zombie]

The full command to summon mobs with gear is this (as of version 1.9):

`/summon Zombie ~0 ~1 ~0 {HandItems:[{Mainhand},{Off-Hand}],ArmorItems:[{Feet},{Legs},{Chest},{Head}]}`

To specify an item use its minecraft name (`diamond_helmet` for example) instead of their id. 
Here is a [list](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values/Item_IDs).

PS: You can equip (almost) any item, not just armor.

[image: BigHead]